# Who inherits how much?

Tags: halacha, money, estates-inheritance

Imagine the following scenario:

A man dies. He owns 100,000 ₪ cash, 3 kilograms of gold, a 100 square meter house with a garden, a car, and stocks worth 20,000 dollars.

He leaves behind:

- A wife (Jewish)
- Child one: 32 year old women (from his wife)
- Child two: 30-year-old man (born from an affair and not his wife's child - Jewish)
- Child three: 20 year old man (from his wife)
- Child four: 15-year-old male (non-Jewish and born from an affair)
- Child five: 12-year-old boy (from his wife)
- 4 Grandchildren all from Child one and all boys, the oldest one is 13
  years old.

According to Halacha. Who would inherit what and why?

Comment: *Le'halachah*: The type of assets is irrelevant, all are summed by value. Non-Jewish progeny are not heirs. The wife is not a heiress but is entitled to be supported from the deceased estate as per the *kesuvah*. Female progeny do not inherit unless specified otherwise in the *tzavaah* (will). Grandchildren do not inherit unless they are children of a deceased child and so inherit their father's rights. The *bechor* gets a double portion. Nowadays the *bechor* tends not to get an absolute double portion, but is generally given something of significance to indicate his special status.

Comment: @TheG type of asset does matter for bechor (though here there isn't a bechor)

Comment: @TheGRAPKE thank you. Is the bechor considered as such, if He was born from an affair, as long as he is jewish ?

Comment: If the very first child of this man is a male born to a Jewish mother, then yes, quite clearly, even if born out of wedlock. The Talmud applies Deut. 21:17 to this situation.  https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.21.17?ven=Metsudah_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009&lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en (in your hypothetical, as the first child was a daughter, it's moot).

Comment: @DoubleAA remind me please how the asset matters for *pi shnayim*?

Comment: @shalom הבכור נוטל פי שנים בנכסי האב, ואינו נוטל פי שנים בנכסי האם.
ואינו נוטל פי שנים בשבח, ולא בראוי כבמוחזק likely savings accounts and even brokerage accounts are ראוי since theyre owed by the bank to you

Comment: @DoubleAA right, thanks ... never thought about savings accounts that way. *Mistama* the same goes for stocks too? (Rabbi Willig shlit'a differs with RH"S and doesn't require one to sell their stocks in InBev or General Mills before Pesach -- there is no cereal/beer with your name on it at this moment!)

Comment: @Shalom That's why I included brokerage accounts. If you own paper stock certificates (do those still exist?) that I'd guess'd be muchzak.

Comment: This case is extremely specific. I suspect it is asking for a practical ruling. Voting to close.